# clojure - ordered pairwise combination of 2 lists

Tags: list, clojure, combinations

Being quite new to clojure I am still struggling with its functions. If I have 2 lists, say "1234" and "abcd" I need to make all possible ordered lists of length 4. Output I want to have is for length 4 is:

```
("1234" "123d" "12c4" "12cd" "1b34" "1b3d" "1bc4" "1bcd" 
 "a234" "a23d" "a2c4" "a2cd" "ab34" "ab3d" "abc4" "abcd")
```

which 2^n in number depending on the inputs.

I have written a the following function to generate by random walk a single string/list. 
 The argument [par] would be something like ["1234" "abcd"]

```
(defn make-string [par] (let [c1 (first par) c2 (second par)] ;version 3 0.63 msec
  (apply str (for [loc (partition 2 (interleave c1 c2)) 
                   :let [ch (if (< (rand) 0.5) (first loc) (second loc))]] 
                     ch))))
```

The output will be 1 of the 16 ordered lists above. Each of the two input lists will always have equal length, say 2,3,4,5, up to say 2^38 or within available ram. In the above function I have tried to modify it to generate all ordered lists but failed. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Mikera is right that you need to use recursion, but you can do this while being both more concise and more general - why work with two strings, when you can work with N sequences?

```
(defn choices [colls]
  (if (every? seq colls)
    (for [item (map first colls)
          sub-choice (choices (map rest colls))]
      (cons item sub-choice))
    '(())))

(defn choose-strings [& strings]
  (for [chars (choices strings)]
    (apply str chars)))

user> (choose-strings "123" "abc")
("123" "12c" "1b3" "1bc" "a23" "a2c" "ab3" "abc")
```

This recursive nested-for is a very useful pattern for creating a sequence of paths through a "tree" of choices. Whether there's an actual tree, or the same choice repeated over and over, or (as here) a set of N choices that don't depend on the previous choices, this is a handy tool to have available.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is great and helps improve my clojure.

Answer (score 6):

You can also take advantage of the `cartesian-product` from the [clojure.math.combinatorics](https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics) package, although this requires some pre- and post-transformation of your data:

```
(ns your-namespace (:require clojure.math.combinatorics))

(defn str-combinations [s1 s2]
     (->>
        (map vector s1 s2) ; regroup into pairs of characters, indexwise
        (apply clojure.math.combinatorics/cartesian-product) ; generate combinations
        (map (partial apply str))))  ; glue seqs-of-chars back into strings

> (str-combinations "abc" "123")
("abc" "ab3" "a2c" "a23" "1bc" "1b3" "12c" "123")
>
```

Comment: From a python forum I thought of cartesian product but didn't know how to adapt it to my problem. Thank you for this solution.

Comment: @Brian You might benefit from solving some problems at 4clojure.com - there are lots of them similar to this one there. And checking solutions from other users (e.g. chouser who I believe is Chris Houser) is a fast way to pick up useful Clojure tricks.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to make the function recursive, calling itself on the remainder of the list at each step.

You can do something like:

```
(defn make-all-strings [string1 string2]
  (if (empty? string1) 
    [""]
    (let [char1 (first string1)
          char2 (first string2)
          following-strings (make-all-strings (next string1) (next string2))]
      (concat 
        (map #(str char1 %) following-strings)
        (map #(str char2 %) following-strings)))))

(make-all-strings "abc" "123")
=> ("abc" "ab3" "a2c" "a23" "1bc" "1b3" "12c" "123")
```

Comment: Thank you for your straight forward solution to my problem. It also helps improve my clojure.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn combine-strings [a b]
  (if (seq a)
    (for [xs (combine-strings (rest a) (rest b))
          x [(first a) (first b)]]
      (str x xs))
    [""]))
```

Now that I wrote it I realize it's a less generic version of amalloiy's one.

Comment: Like this one: simple, sleek and elegant. Can't see how it can be any simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the binary digits of numbers between 0 and 16 to form your combinations:
if a bit is zero select from the first string otherwise the second.

E.g. 6 = 2r0110 => "1bc4", 13 = 2r1101 => "ab3d", etc.

```
(map (fn [n] (apply str (map #(%1 %2)
                             (map vector "1234" "abcd")
                             (map #(if (bit-test n %) 1 0) [3 2 1 0])))); binary digits
     (range 0 16))
=> ("1234" "123d" "12c4" "12cd" "1b34" "1b3d" "1bc4" "1bcd" "a234" "a23d" "a2c4" "a2cd" "ab34" "ab3d" "abc4" "abcd")
```

The same approach can apply to generating combinations from more than 2 strings.
Say you have 3 strings ("1234" "abcd" "ABCD"), there will be 81 combinations (3^4). Using base-3 ternary digits:

```
(defn ternary-digits [n] (reverse (map #(mod % 3) (take 4 (iterate #(quot % 3) n))))
(map (fn [n] (apply str (map #(%1 %2)
                             (map vector "1234" "abcd" "ABCD")
                             (ternary-digits n)
     (range 0 81))
```

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you. I have struggled with using map correctly; your function definitely helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
(def c1 "1234")
(def c2 "abcd")

(defn make-string [c1 c2]
  (map #(apply str %)
       (apply map vector
              (map (fn [col rep]
                     (take (math/expt 2 (count c1))
                           (cycle (apply concat
                                         (map #(repeat rep %) col)))))
                   (map vector c1 c2)
                   (iterate #(* 2 %) 1)))))

(make-string c1 c2)
=> ("1234" "a234" "1b34" "ab34" "12c4" "a2c4" "1bc4" "abc4" "123d" "a23d" "1b3d" "ab3d" "12cd" "a2cd" "1bcd" "abcd")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this problem. Your solution and the others have gone a long way to expand my appreciation of clojure.